# How to get package depencies for Prism and Unity working?

Tags: wpf, appium, prism, unity-container, mstest

I have a WPF application built on .Net 4.8, Prism and Unity, using PackageReference in the project files. Every once in a while I update Nuget references to the newest ones. The packages related to Prism and Unity repeatedly have been a pain in the arse.

Now is such a moment again. Or rather, the past DAYS. I am trying to use packages like

- Prism.Wpf 7.2.0.1422
- Unity.Container 5.11.8

I keep bumping into the dreaded "The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference", again & again in various variations. Seeing warnings like "Found conflicts between different versions of ... that could not be resolved", or "explicit binding redirect on ... conflicts with an autogenerated binding redirect".

I have been tinkering with this a lot, checking a whole dependency tree, removing, adding, or changing redirects, adding or removing packages. Of course searching on the web. It has driven me nuts. How to get out of this, and prevent it for the future?!

I don't know if this is combination of bugs somewhere, or just me not understanding how to use it. So I will put this as a question.

How on earth am I supposed to get things working?!

- Set AutoGenerateBindingRedirects or not?
- Set explicit redirects or not? If so, for which versions, to which other version? What about the publicKeyToken?
- What about testing projects using MSTest, Moq, Appium, do they need a different approach?

Frankly, I was under the impression that using Nuget to install packages would just take care of all that, particularly using PackageReference. Well apparently, it doesn't.

I am at a loss. Is there anyone who can direct me to a valid approach?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you confirmed that all *your* projects use the same version of all NuGet packages?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
But yes, they are all on the same versions. I just ran through them.